# Pod install, proxy issue

Tags: ios, proxy, cocoapods

I'm trying to run **pod install** in vain :

```
Analyzing dependencies
Creating shallow clone of spec repo `master` from `https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git`
[!] Unable to add a source with url `https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git` named `master`.
You can try adding it manually in `~/.cocoapods/repos` or via `pod repo add`.
```

I think i have a proxy issue, but i don't know how to fix it. These is the result when i try **pod setup**

```
Setting up CocoaPods master repo
[!] /usr/bin/git clone https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git master --depth=1

Cloning into 'master'...

fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git/':Received HTTP code 503 from proxy after CONNECT
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30934258/4712174

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It is possible, that your system proxy settings do not apply to the bash. Type this into bash before running `pod install`:

```
export http_proxy=<YOUR_HTTP_PROXY>
export https_proxy=<YOUR_HTTPS_PROXY>
```

If it helps, you can make proxy settings load when bash starts by adding above commands to the `.bash_profile` (create file if it does not exist) in your home directory.

Answer (score 5):

I think you forgott to set your newly install Xcode on Command-linetool path location. please check that on **Xcode-->Preferences-->Locations-->Command line tool --> set your Xcode**.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I think you need to config your own cocoapods dependencies manager using http_proxy variable

Step 1: Config your proxy setting for both of http and https at current project directory:

```
export http_proxy=username:password@proxy_server_ip:proxy_port
export https_proxy=username:password@proxy_server_ip:proxy_port
```

You can use the following command to show proxy settings:

```
echo $http_proxy
```

Step 2: Install cocoapods with http_proxy variable already defined before

```
sudo gem install cocoapods -p $http_proxy
```

Finally: Install your own pod libs

```
pod install
```

These worked for me.