# Pod install command with error

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I've been trying to use `cocoapods` and install them into my project but its giving me this error while trying to install it in the project location. its kinda confusing ?

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.37.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:127: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local in PATH, mode 040777
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-core-0.37.2/lib/cocoapods-core/standard_error.rb:88:in `message': incompatible character encodings: ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8 (Encoding::CompatibilityError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/claide-0.8.1/lib/claide/command.rb:367:in `handle_exception'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/claide-0.8.1/lib/claide/command.rb:315:in `rescue in run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/claide-0.8.1/lib/claide/command.rb:303:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.37.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:46:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.37.2/bin/pod:44:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    from /usr/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

replace this character " ‘ " with this " ' " in your podfile and try to install again.

it's happen to me when I copy pod line from somewhere else (like Evernote), some text editors automatically change this character. Usually it's like this :

```
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.0'
```

but when I take from other editor, it could be like this :

```
pod ‘AFNetworking‘, ‘~> 2.0‘
```

Comment: your amazing @gyer :)

Answer (score 2):

Follow this steps:

1.open terminal.

2.pod setup // it's take some time to download podfiles

3.pod list //(optional)to see the list of pod

4.cd Desktop//(your project path)

5.cd CoacPods (your project name)

6.vim podfile

7.pod install

Answer (score 1):

Check this out *chmod go-w /opt/local/bin* at a shell prompt (depending on permissions you may need to sudo to do that).