# Cocoapod installation issue on terminal when running pod install command

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I am trying to install pod but it gives the following error when run the `pod install` command.

```
$ pod
$ cd path of project
$ pod init
$ pod *** (which I want to install)
$ pod install
```

After those command I got this issue:

> `[!] The`master` repo requires CocoaPods 1.0.0 -  (currently using 0.39.0)
>   Update CocoaPods, or checkout the appropriate tag in the repo.
>
> [!] Your Podfile has had smart quotes sanitised. To avoid issues in the future, you should not use TextEdit for editing it. If you are not using TextEdit, you should turn off smart quotes in your editor of choice.`

Comment: Edit your podfile using Xcode editor. Also update your CocoaPods.

Comment: take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39481636/updating-to-latest-version-of-cocoapods

Comment: update your cocoa pods

Comment: @nandini please search the answer in SO before posting a question. it says **Update CocoaPods** search it in SO

Comment: @Ganesh Sir i searched it on so and i found a command 'sudo gem install cocoapods' which i run on terminal. Pls check the steps of commands>>

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30934134/pod-install-command-with-error/30934258#30934258

Comment: 1) sudo gem install cocoapods                                                                      2) cd path of project                                                                                      3) pod init                                                                                                   4) pod install                                                                                             but again i got this error.

Comment: did you update the cocoapods? check your cocoapods version is the latest one or not..

Answer (score 2):

The first error is complaining about the version of CocoaPods you have installed. You can verify your version with the following command:

```
pod --version
```

Assuming you need to go to 1.0.0 or above, you can upgrade with:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

The second warning indicates an issue with the quotes in your Podfile. You can open it in XCode, or via a command line tool line Nano and verify that all the quotes are standard quotes like this `'` or `"`.

Odds are, your quotes will have slants to them like this ( `“` ), which is the source of the warning.

Answer (score 0):

What you did wrong is clearly stated in the error message:

> Your Podfile has had **smart quotes sanitised**. To avoid issues in the future, you should not use TextEdit for editing it. If you are not using TextEdit, you should turn off smart quotes in your editor of choice.

You must have been using this type of quotes:

```
“”
```

You should be using these instead:

```
""
```

By default, TextEdit will use the former so you should use Xcode to edit your Podfile instead.